# AgGrid Excel Export Stripping Leading 0's

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid

I am trying to export a grid to Excel. Values in the `model` cells are not exported correctly. Instead of exporting as

```
0001458
0008451
0008451
```

They display as:

```
1458
8451
8451
```

The actual values coming from the API returning the data for `model` is coming as `string`, so:

```
'0001458'
'0008451'
'0008451'
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-r3sjfn?file=index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(
      [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: '0001458', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: '0008451', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: '0085452', price: 72000 },
      ]
    );
  }, 300);
});

 
const App = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  const initData = useRef([]);
  const gridApi = useRef();

  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price', editable: true },
  ]);

  const gridReady = (params) => {
    gridApi.current = params?.api;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let data = myPromise
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setRowData(data);
        initData.current = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
  }, []);

  const exportExcel = () => {
    gridApi.current.exportDataAsExcel();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={exportExcel}>Back to original</button>

      <br></br>

      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
        <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs} onGridReady={gridReady}></AgGridReact>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please check out the following: https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-data-types/

Comment: Did try that, didnt help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/excel-export-data-types/

This is how you can implement **Thomas Renger**'s comment

Define your types

```
const excelStyles = useMemo(() => [
  {
    id: 'stringType',
    dataType: 'String',
  },
  // ...
]);
```

Pass as a prop

```
<AgGridReact
  ref={gridRef}
  rowData={rowData}
  excelStyles={excelStyles}
/>
```

Define a value getter method (Important)

```
const valueGetter = (params) => {
  return params.data.model;
};
```

Modify your column definitions like that

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
  { field: 'make' },
  {
    field: 'model',
    valueGetter: valueGetter,
    field: 'Model (String)',
    cellClass: 'stringType',
  },
  { field: 'price', editable: true },
]);
```

Result
[image: Result]

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/BK0WN7mLOcm0kzpk?preview